# ajax implementation in zend

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

I want to implement ajax functionality in zend frame work. So, please try to give one simple example to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two ways using ajax in a zend framework project. Make sure you have [**ZendX**](http://code.google.com/p/zendx/) in your library folder. It helps you working with ajax.

The first and most straight forward way is to use it like in any other web project. Copy all your java-script files in the `/public/js/` folder.

In my project I use [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/). So in your `_initViewHelpers` function you have to enable jQuery:

```
ZendX_JQuery::enableView($view);
```

In your layout script you could do this:

```
if ($this->jQuery()->isEnabled()){
    $this->jQuery()->setLocalPath($this->baseUrl ().
                            '/js/jquery/jquery.min.1.4.4.js')
    echo $this->jQuery()->uiEnable();
}
```

and in any view script this:

```
$this->jQuery ()->enable ()->addJavascriptFile ( $this->baseUrl () .
                                                '/js/frontend.js' )
```

Another way is to let zend create the ajax functions. Watch this [HOW TO](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyU3pKkGdII), it shows you from the beginning how to use ajax in zend framework projects.

Answer (score 0):

Into my Bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initJQuery()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    ZendX_JQuery::enableView($view);
    $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
    $view->jQuery()->setRenderMode(ZendX_JQuery::RENDER_JAVASCRIPT | ZendX_JQuery::RENDER_JQUERY_ON_LOAD);
}
```

> as you can see you need ZendX into
>   your library

in Layout.phtml into the

```
echo $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js')
        ->appendFile('/js/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js'); ?>
```

and you'll have JQuery available all-around, then, where you should expect an Ajax response, as I did:

```
private function noLayout() {
    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
    $viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->disableLayout();
}
```

this function will disable the layout and will not require a view, so you can do an echo from the Controller Action, as example:

```
public function listAction() {
    $this->noLayout();
        echo json_encode(array('success' => TRUE));
}
```

This is "my way", let me know if you find something "better" or just different

Comment: No need to do that "noLayout" stuff. You can use `$this->_helper->json($data)` to send anything as response formated as json. It also sends propper headers and stuff, disables layout, viewscript, etc...